# Why my function in Views.py is not correct?

Tags: django, django-views

I have a Notification List view and this function

```
def mark_as_read(request, notification_id):
    notification = get_object_or_404(Notification.objects.filter(pk=notification_id).exclude(viewed_at__isnull=False))
    notification.viewed_at = datetime.datetime.now()
    notification.save()
    return redirect('users:notification')
```

It works good but I think it is written not correct? Any body can tell it correct here working get_object_or_404?

Answer (score 1):

It is **correct**, but you can make it shorter and cleaner with:

```
notification = get_object_or_404(Notification, pk=notification_id, viewed_at=None)
```

It is also better to work with the [**`timezone.now`** function [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.now):

```
from django.utils.timezone import now

def mark_as_read(request, notification_id):
    notification = get_object_or_404(Notification, pk=notification_id, viewed_at=None)
    notification.viewed_at = now()
    notification.save()
    return redirect('users:notification')
```

or with the timestamp of the database:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Now

def mark_as_read(request, notification_id):
    notification = get_object_or_404(Notification, pk=notification_id, viewed_at=None)
    notification.viewed_at = Now()
    notification.save()
    return redirect('users:notification')
```

The view you are implementing should only be triggered with a POST or PATCH request, not with a GET request, since GET requests are supposed to have *no* side effects.